# Trying to include a php file that connects to a seperate database on a Wordpress page

Tags: php, wordpress, include

quite new here and not much of a developer. I've seen this questions asked on this forum but I think I have a situation that's a bit more unique than others and I'm not sure how to approach to it.

Basically my client has a mysql database(it's on the same server as wordpress db) and a php file that works with a few other files (one that actually connects to the database) and outputs some data and html formatting. I've been trying to integrate this into a wordpress page but the include command doesn't seem to work. This is probably because it's trying to connect to a second database, because when I include a php file with just an echo, it displays fine.

I've read that you can use something called a wpdb class but I don't know where it should go or how it's used it in this situation. If anyone could maybe direct me into the right direction, I would really appreciate it.

Comment: What exactly do you mean when you say "the include command doesn't seem to work."?  Are you getting any sort of error messages?  Can you provide the code that you believe to be problematic?

Comment: on the wordpress template, I've added <?php include("file.php") ;?> which doesn't return anything and also breaks the theme. The php itself works fine. I think the code works fine, I'm asking more of a suggestion as to how to make it work since it connects to a second database

Comment: Can you put wordpress in debug mod so we can see the errors, or pull them from the log?

Comment: Not getting any errors from debug mode and it doesn't create an error log either (I enabled both)

Comment: @Ihsan First of all let's assume all the databases are in the same server and are accessible. Second, when you call the include function the way you did, the system understands that all the necessary includes are inside the same folder you're writing the code into, including the "few other files" that are needed to do the connection. I'm sure that the problem is related with the path of the included files.